# how to use laravel url and route helper in $ajax (js file)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

how to translate url like this

```
http://localhost/event/add
```

but i got always like this  when i submit form

```
http://localhost/%7B%7B%20url('event/add')%20%7D%7D
```

my js code is

```
 $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{ url('event/add') }}",
                data: form,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("yes :- " + JSON.stringify(data));
                 }
        },'json');
```

my web.php file

`Route::post('/event/add','eventController@create')->name('event.Add')`;

Comment: your route code please send.

Comment: @KuldeepMishra i updated my question

Comment: try create `var url = "{{ url('event/add') }}"` and put `url:url`

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos same issue http://localhost/%7B%7B%20url('event/add')%20%7D%7D

Comment: delete `form` in your `ajax`

Comment: create var url = "{{ url('event/add') }}" in your blade view and use that variable inisde javascript file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not call laravel codes inside js file unless js codes are inside laravel blade views file.

so to call laravel codes is either you pass them as html tags attributes inside your view then call them with javascript inside js file

i.e myview.blade.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="myurl" url="{{url('event/add')}}" />
```

then in your js file

```
var myurl = $('#myurl").attr('url');
$.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: myurl,
                data: form,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("yes :- " + JSON.stringify(data));
                 }
        },'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this example,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
  });

$url = '{{url('event/add')}}';

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: $url,
    success:function(data) {
        $("#msg").html(data.msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in console @Sobin Augustine

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript file can't render the php/blade code. It doesn't work in a .js file as they are not parsed in .js file. So you can use some tricks to get your rendered/translated url by blade as given below.

*In the following examples I am assuming the name of your `blade` file is `view.blade.php` and `javascript` file is `script.js`*

**First Solution:**

In `view.blade.php` write the following code

```
<script>
   var add_event_url = "{{ url('event/add') }}"
</script>
```

*Include your js file below the script tags.*

Then you can use `add_event_url` variable in your javascript file
in `script.js` file

```
$.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: add_event_url, //http://localhost/event/add
                data: form,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("yes :- " + JSON.stringify(data));
                 }
        },'json');
```

**Second Solution:**
You can use route or url helper in an HTML element attribute and on click you can get the parsed url as given below
in your `view.blade.php` file

```
<a href="{{ url('event/create') }}" id="create_event">Add Event</a>
```

and in `script.js` file

```
$(document).on('click', '#create_event', function(){
    var add_event_url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: add_event_url, //http://localhost/event/add
                data: form,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("yes :- " + JSON.stringify(data));
                 }
        },'json');

});
```

I hope it will help.