# How to call controller function for ajax url laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, url, routes

I am using the function (delivery-update) of contoller (OrdersController) from the view(resources\views\customer\edit_order.blade.php) via ajax url. My javascript is located at `localhost:8072/myapp/public/theme/js/custom.js`

```
$.ajax({        
        url: 'delivery-update',
        type: "POST",
.....
```

But when I debugged the url in network console. the request is going to url `localhost:8072/myapp/customer/edit_order/delivery-update` but I need the url request to `localhost:8072/myapp/orders/delivery-update`

I tried,

```
url: 'orders/delivery-update'   //but it takes to localhost:8072/myapp/customer/edit_order/orders/delivery-update
```

My route.php

```
Route::post('orders/delivery-update', 'Admin\OrdersController@delivery_update');
```

Pls. any suggestions would be great..

Comment: @AndrewHardiman edited it is in localhost:8072/myapp/public/theme/js/custom.js

Comment: try using `url: '/orders/delivery-update'`

Comment: tried but same as localhost:8072/myapp/customer/edit_order/orders/delivery-update

Comment: try to follow this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950976/5958526 
hope it will work